# "You need to add at least 2 non-Android TV screenshots"

Tags: android

In my Developer Console for Google Play, I dragged two PNGs at 2:1 ratio (1000px x 500px) into the Graphic Assets slots for the TV and they were accepted. But I still get the message, "You need to add at least 2 non-Android TV screenshots" when I click to publish the app. So it remains in Draft mode.

I'm unsure what I should be doing differently to finalize it:

- I signed out then signed back in and the issue persists.
- I am using the Chrome browser.
- I tried in the Firefox browser.

This app was uploaded in Alpha Testing, if that matters. Also, I thought TV images were optional.

Comment: The message is definitely misleading, at least for me which does not have English as first language. I guess it should be read as "You need to add at least 2 non-**Android-TV** screenshots" which means that what is required is at least two screenshots that are *NOT* for tv.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You also need to provide at least two phone or tablet screens.

Comment: But it is really stupid requirement in case I have TV-only app.

Comment: I have a phone only app with one screen only... This is google stupidity in action!

Answer (score 7):

The message is misleading, stays there even when I have uploaded two TV screenshots. They mean you have to upload at least two screenshots per requested type!

Comment: This caught me too. You need a phone, 7 inch tablet, 10 inch tablet, high-res, feature and the TV images to publish even if it just a vanilla 'phone App..

Answer (score 7):

The accepted answer is not correct, at least in 2016. TV and table screenshots are not required. In order to get rid of this error:

1. Upload at least two screenshots (to any of the categories, e.g. for mobile).
2. Click the "Save Draft" button (top right corner). This will apply changes, and error will go away.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add 2 screenshots in Tablet section thats how I solved it.